# Если мой почтовый адрес Google отправил в спам, значит ли это, что теперь он навсегда в чёрном списке или это можно исправить?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

Начинаю осваивать отправку почты из PHP-скрипта и попробовал по первому примеру в сети отправить письмо на почту Gmail. На моём сервере (VPS) почта вообще не настроена. Я стал больше читать и узнал много нюансов, почему письма попадают в спам Google, в том числе и то, что нужна PTR запись. Но, теперь мне страшно пробовать отправлять тестовые письма на Gmail, так как я боюсь что если IP моего сервера попадёт в черный список Gmail, то это навсегда. Так ли это?

Comment: А вы сперва настройте PTR, DKIM, SPF и DMARC, а уже потом отправляйте. Пока в процессе настройки отправите парочку тестовых писем — ничего страшного случиться ещё не успеет. Вы же не массовую рассылку делаете? Тогда и отправлять ip в чёрный список пока ещё незачем

Comment: @andreymal походу ещё много чего мне предстоит узнать. Просто у меня сейчас бесплатный домен от freenom, не знаю пропустит ли гугл его, даже если я выполню все эти условия. Я пока думал потренироваться так, а потом уже когда буду уверен, что всё освоил перейти на нормальный платный домен, с которого и будет отправляться почта. А без PTR, DKIM, SPF и DMARC гугл 100% перекинет письма в спам?